# Proof of $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{1-x}=-1$ using $\epsilon-\delta$ definiton

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I proved the limit with $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, but I have one question. I am not sure, that I understand it right. I would like to compare my proof with proof in book. So we have:

$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{1-x}=-1$

$\textbf{My proof}$: Suppose $0<\lvert x-2 \rvert<\delta$, then $$\left\lvert \frac{1}{1-x}-(-1)\right\rvert=\left\lvert \frac{1}{1-x}+1\right\rvert=\left\lvert \frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1-x}{1-x}\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{x-2}{1-x}\right\rvert=\frac{\lvert x-2\rvert}{\lvert 1-x \rvert}$$ and now I have a question. The book says that if $\lvert x-2 \rvert<\frac{1}{2}$ then $x>\frac{3}{2}$ and $\lvert x-1 \rvert> \frac{1}{2}$ and from here $0<\frac{1}{1-x}<2$ and therefore $$\frac{\lvert x-2 \rvert}{\lvert 1-x \rvert}<2\cdot \lvert x-2 \rvert<2\cdot \delta=\epsilon$$ So we take $\delta:=\min\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{2}\}$. But instead of to say $\vert x-2 \rvert<\frac{1}{2}$, I said that $\lvert x-2 \rvert<\frac{1}{3}$ and then I proved the same. Needless to say that my $\delta$ is another $\delta:=\min\{\frac{1}{3},\frac{2\cdot \epsilon}{3}\}$. It's not a mistake, right? Can I make so? This condition $\lvert x-2 \rvert <\frac{1}{2}$ I can choose by myself, right?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can take $\lvert x-2\rvert<a$ for whatever $a>0$ you would like, you just have to adjust your $\delta$ accordingly. In your case, the solution found $a=\frac{1}{2}$ to be a convenient choice, but $a=\frac{1}{3}$, as you chose, works just as well. The point is to show that your choice of $\delta$ works, and as you have done that it is perfectly fine. Remember: there is not one *right* choice of $\delta$, but rather you find one that works.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect explanation!